# Flex-wrap issues on safari

Tags: cross-browser, flexbox

I'm trying to have two elements fill their container and wrap when they reach a certain minimum size. The code I have works perfectly on all browsers other than safari & I can't figure out an alternative. It appears to be an issue with flex-basis: 0

Here's the issue:

http://www.cssdesk.com/RKeNY

Both display differently in safari and chrome. When the container width is changed on safari the flex-wrap has no effect.

Comment: Experienced the same - I haven't found any other solution than to not use flex-basis.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
-webkit-flex:1 1 auto;
```

instead of

```
-webkit-flex:1;
```

on the flex elements.

This is discussed here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1414

Specifically:

> hexalys commented 28 days ago
>
> To enable wrapping you'll need to need to specifically set flex: auto
> (equivalent to flex: 1 1 auto;) or set both property flex-shrink:
> 1;and flex-basis: auto. The flex: 1; you have in your code does flex:
> 1 1 0px; technically allowing shrink, but apparently there is a bug
> with the webkit prefixed version in Safari which does not allow a flex
> wrap in that condition, while it correctly does on the unprefixed
> version of Chrome and Firefox.