# Flex-wrap iOS Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flex wrap is not working on Safari and Chrome - **this seems to be well documented but none of the fixes I have read work in my situation.**

On iOS Safari and Chrome, the rows simply don't wrap and will go outside of the container. I've tried running it through Autoprefixer, but still no joy.

Here's a reduced test case: https://codepen.io/jciw/pen/yxPebP

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.column-one-third {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column-one-third">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284540/flex-wrap-issues-on-safari?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360526/row-wrap-in-flex-box-not-wrapping-in-safari/30792851#30792851

Comment: So don't use `width` - use the `flex` property instead?

Comment: I've added that to the row but still the issue persists.

Comment: Where? It's not in your code and it should be on the `.column-one-third` divs ` `.column-one-third {flex:1 0 33.333%;}` not `width`.

Comment: I have changed this on CodePen and the issue still persists.